# Git how to find or add .gitignore

Tags: git

I am having a problem adding the text file .gitignore in my terminal session.  I open the command line prompt and navigate to the folder that holds the .gitignore file and a hello_git.py file.

When I type git status; the Python file shows up but not the .gitignore.  I can add the Python file, by typing git add .  The other file will not add or commit.

What should I be doing in order to use the .gitignore file?

Comment: Is the gitignore at the root of the repo? Does the gitignore have any text contents?

Comment: Try `git ls-files` to see, which files git already has stored. Perhaps `.gitignore` was already committed before.

Comment: The contents of the file has something in it.  It says gitignore.  When I use ls-files the .gitignore file is not in the list.

Comment: I made the gitignore file in Sublime text editor.  Could that be why?

Comment: I did add a repo but I am not sure what the root is?

Comment: This seems strange. Are you sure the `.gitignore` file is present in the same directory (folder) as the `hello_git.py` file that *does* show up in `git status`? (The output of `ls -A` or whatever your OS's "show all files, including hidden ones", command could be useful here.) If so, what OS and Git version are you using?

Comment: Git version - 2.33.1 64 bit   and OS version - Window 10 Home 20H2.

Comment: If I type \ git add .gitignore instead of \ git add .  The message I receive is "The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files: .gitignore.  Below that message in orange text it says: "hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.  hint: Turn this message off by running hint:"git config advice.addignoredFile false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick introduction on how to use the same gitignore globally to all your projects if ever you would be interested in it as you were not too deep in your explanation:

```sh
touch ~/.gitignore_global # This creates a global.gitignore file in the current directory.

git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global # This command will override all patterns in /.gitignore global in all situations.

# Following this do not forget to edit the .gitignore_global
```

However, as far as I can tell, you cannot push your own .gitignore file. Given that, I would like you to double-check that the content is not empty, and if it is, please update it before looking at your git status (as @evolutionxbox also stated). Additionally, attempt to include it in your commit; if that does not work, you can force it, but this is never a great recommendation:

```sh
git add --force [...]/.gitignore

#
# Man git add:
# -f, --force Allow adding otherwise ignored files.
# https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add
#
```

Cheers, I hope this helps; remember to agree with the solution if it works for you. Have a wonderful day,

Simon.

Comment: You say *"double-check that the content is not empty"* -- how does this prevent the file being added to the commit or displayed by `git status`?

Comment: I have a book called Crash Course for Python.  Appendix D has an intro to Version Control.  I was able to make a Python_File.py.  The Python_File.py file says: Print(“hello git world”).  I made a file in my computer in the Documents folder called git_practice to save my Python_File.py in.  Then I made the .gitignore file on sublime text editor and inside the file it says gitignore.  I saved it to the git_practice folder.  I used these commands in my command line: git init, git status, and git add .  That is all I have done so far.

Comment: Be careful with a "Documents" folder: on Windows and macOS this folder is often cloud-synchronized, i.e., if you work on another computer, the OS will magically transport the files over the cloud to your local system. Cloud-synced folders *do not work with Git*. The problem is basically that both the cloud-sync software *and* Git demand *exclusive* control here at times, and one wins (usually the cloud sync) which makes the other fail.

Comment: I took the text out of the .gitignore and that allowed me to change the status of the file.  I'd give votes but I only have 11 status.  thanks!